# Don't ban based on IP address

Tags: discussion, post-ban, ip-address

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/158209), automatic bans are at a lower level than the account, i.e. bans are based on IP address.

There are two problems with this:

1. There are [many people who share IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) that can negatively affected as a side effect of the ban.
2. Banning an IP doesn't really accomplish much of anything as far as preventing a person from continuing to post: it's not that hard to change your IP address, and you can always just switch computers or networks.

IP bans are ineffectual in stopping the activity of malignant people, and have collateral damage that can affect normal people. In short: **don't ban IP addresses**.

Instead, use account bans. They don't accomplish anything less than an IP ban, but they don't cause collateral damage.

Comment: And then what? Assuming you are not contesting the post ban itself, how would it work?

Comment: @YannisRizos What does an IP ban accomplish that an account ban doesn't?

Comment: People who generally are not smart enough to read and respond to the many warning signs they will receive before a question ban usually are not smart enough to realize "*oh, I need to change my IP*".

Comment: @Peter It stops quite a few people from creating secondary accounts. While it's true that there might be some false positives every now and then or that some people may change their IP, from what I've seen it's working as expected more often than not.

Comment: It depends whether people are doing it through stupidity or just a disregard toward rules. Why is *let me change accounts* such an easier conclusion to make than *let me change computers* or *let me switch my network*?

Comment: @YannisRizos It doesn't prevent people from creating secondary accounts. Even with an IP ban, it's trivial to create a secondary account. How can you know people *aren't* creating secondary accounts? If, as far as the system can tell, it's a legitimate different account, there's no way to track it.

Comment: @PeterOlson I don't know why, but it is what it is. Typically (anecdotal) post banned users that don't care of reversing the ban the right way, will go for a secondary account or, you know, asking their coding questions on MSO.

Comment: @PeterOlson Creating a secondary account is not an issue, didn't phrase that correctly, what I meant was creating a secondary account and using it for the sole purpose of circumventing the ban. They can create all the accounts they want, but if the ban is at a lower level they can't use them...

Comment: @PeterOlson [Case in point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150028/how-to-slide-image-one-by-one-on-android-programatically) <sigh>

Comment: @YannisRizos Sure they can. It only prevents them from circumventing the ban when they have the same IP address, which is like putting a chair in front of the door and pretending the door is locked.

Comment: @PeterOlson Yes and some do (I'm battling such a troll on Programmers _right now_). But most are simply not smart enough, read waiwai933's comment again.

Comment: @YannisRizos I think there's a selection bias here. The people who switch somehow to make it so that they're not using the site with the same IP do not have any observable behavior because the system cannot recognize that they are the same person. The people who are too clueless to switch of course will come up with a different solution.

Comment: @PeterOlson Going in circles, let's try this another way: Your question is based on the premise that IP bans _may_ produce false positives. Any data to back that up, even anecdotal? The very next question posted on MSO after yours is by someone trying to circumvent the ban by asking a coding question here, anecdotal, but...

Comment: @YannisRizos, there have been cases here where coworkers have managed to get each other banned through bad question asking.  These are in the minority.

Comment: @Charles Certainly, I'm not denying that there were instances of false positives, I'm denying it's a problem affecting a lot of people. There will be false positives in any post ban mechanism we can think of... Right now I think IP ban false positives are quite rare and handled appropriately. If they are still in the amounts that the team can handle them manually, I'd say the IP ban is working fairly well.

Comment: @YannisRizos Are you disagreeing with the premise that IP bans *may* produce false positives? Further, do you have any evidence that IP bans are significantly more effective than account bans? How do you address the selection bias point I just made?

Comment: @PeterOlson `Are you disagreeing with the premise that IP bans may produce false positives` Did you somehow fail to read my previous comment? Also I'm ignoring the selection bias point you made, not interested in addressing it, sorry.

Comment: @YannisRizos All things else being equal, nobody being effected by a side effect of an IP ban is better than it happening. (You commented while I was writing mine sorry) If you aren't willing to account for a potential error in your argument, I feel like it's no longer worthwhile to discuss this with you.

Comment: @PeterOlson Selection bias could actually be pretty easy to detect in some cases.  Consider this plausible scenario: I ask a question that's downvoted into oblivion, triggering a question ban.  I switch IPs to evade the ban and then ask *the same damn question* (or something similar).  Getting downvoted and banned hasn't changed the question I need help with, so I wouldn't be surprised to see duplicate questions popping up when someone evades the ban.

Comment: @PeterOlson Yannis has acknowledged that there is a potential for harm with IP bans (unintended side effects), but has pointed out that there is also a potential harm from just using account-level bans (bans being ineffective).  The onus is now on you to show that the harm you're concerned with is greater.  You've suggested that the harm from account-level bans is zero (they're just as effective as IP bans), but you haven't convinced anyone of that yet.

Comment: @PeterOlson Didn't really mean that your point wasn't worth my time, just that further discussing in abstract won't take us anywhere. I'm in a slightly more advantageous position than you when it comes to post bans, being a mod, but still all my data are strictly anecdotal. From what I've seen, IP bans work, crudely perhaps, but they do. Account bans just don't work, there's a trivial workaround.  Masking your IP might be trivial for you and I but it's not for most people, I think.

Comment: @blahdiblah That makes sense, especially if the population posting the deviant posts just wants to post the same thing. I guess, in theory, in a world where problem users are purely malicious and will circumvent bans the smart way IP banning has a bad cost-benefit ratio, but in practice the probem users tend to be technically inept and are just persistent in producing bad content, rather than actively trying to break the system.

Comment: All that said, were account bans actually tried and shown to be ineffective, or is this all just theory on both sides?

Comment: IP ban is a good thing, keeps out more of those unintelligible engrish postings behind transparent proxies

Comment: @PeterOlson As Bill mentions in his answer account bans were tried, but that was before my time. However, since account bans are very similar to manually triggered account suspensions, yes, they are ineffective (at least from what I've seen on Programmers).

Comment: In point of fact the team is sensitive to the size of subnets to which IP bans would need to be applied and make some reasonable decision about when to *not* apply IP bans. Details withheld.

Comment: I too agree with this. Most probably my ISP is using a very large PAT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294/1288) to "Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?" where he announced the IP ban for users who have a history of extremely low quality posts.  In particular:

> Based on our queries and a random audit sample of affected accounts / IP addresses, it seems effective, but we'll have to see now that it's deployed and perhaps tweak further.

We used to ban individual accounts for low quality posts, but we found that people would just create new accounts to get around the ban.

Comment: While I understand and agree with the sentiment here, this is likely to be an unsustainable system since for the foreseeable future we are working with the IPv4 address space and many users will be working on dynamic IP connections. The influx of new accounts appears exponential - by trial and error I have found that the current newest user ID is 1782549 (by the time you read this it will likely be more), meaning that the number of registered accounts has more than doubled since I joined just over a year ago. I would propose that the IP blacklisting be temporary - say for 2 weeks.

Comment: Agreed. On today's age, most people change IP addresses every time the open their computer. Sometimes, while walking the street with their mobile phone. I can't really see how IP blocking can be that effective. If the user opens a new account, one of two things would happen. 1. He'll ask more bad questions, and be banned again. 2. He'll learn from his experience and start asking two questions. If it's the former, we don't mind. The community moderation will take care of that. If it's the latter, the community earned another good member.

Comment: lmao nice response

Comment: Sounds like a crap idea to me. You shouldn't try to be to smart. Simple solutions are often best. On a simple level any relation between "user desirability" and "ip address" is a bad idea because many user share ip addresses (corporate firewalls, tor network, other proxies, ...). Another reason not to do it, it's not necessary or even very effective, and has a lot of very nasty user experience as consequence, in short don't ever go there unless you want people to nag at you incessantly.